# Facebook. How limit GraphApi responce by condition

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I limit the IPA response to a specific condition. For example, I want to get all the posts on the wall of the user that are videos ("Type": "video") ?

In FQL is WHERE limit, but I did not find, as there is to get all the posts from the wall of the user? this is only possible through the GRAPHAPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the posts on the wall of a user with FQL, use the `stream` table. Try the first example query on [the documentation page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). You can filter for videos by adding `AND type = 128` to the WHERE clause.

To do this with Graph API you could use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) on the Video object.

Comment: Is the Graph API component of this answer still accurate?  I don't seem to be able to make the second level argument act as a WHERE.

Comment: The v2.2 graph API makes this much easier. You can query `/{uid}/videos/` for all the videos a user is tagged in or `/{uid}/videos/uploaded/` for all the videos a user has uploaded. try it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fvideos&version=v2.2&)